# Why does this if and elif statement not fully execute?

Tags: python

Based on reading the 2.7 documentation, the following code should step through correctly from what I can tell. I call **raw_input(text)** to get an input for variable **age**, but it always returns *You can see rated R movies.*

```
import sys

age = raw_input("What is your age? ")

if age >= 17:
    print "You can see rated R movies."

elif age < 17 and age > 12:
    print "You can see a rated PG-13 movies."

else:
    print "You can only see PG movies!"
```

Based on my logic, if the value passed to **age** is not greater than or equal to 17, it should move onto the next statement. That is not the result I get though. It always returns the Rated R line. For example I input 3 and it still gives me the rated R response. If I flip the > to < then it always returns the "You can only see PG movies!" line.

Thoughts?

Comment: The output of `raw_input` is a string. If you change your if statement to `if "15" >= 17:`, you'll see what's happening.

Comment: By the way, any new Python projects should target Python3

Answer (score 5):

`raw_input` returns a string. you need to convert your input to an `int` before you can test it against numbers.

```
age = int(raw_input('How old are you? '))
```

Comment: **EDIT**

Forget that last response. I fixed it and your answer was correct.

Thank you! I understand now why that wasn't working. I didn't think about it like that, but once you pointed it out it made complete sense.

Comment: Yep, its correct. Mark the answer as correct, to help other people see it and to give him the deserved reputation. :)

Comment: This question should really be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

When you use the raw_input method you are asking to enter a value by keyboard, everything that is entered will be read as a string not as an integer even if you are asking for an integer value.

Your solution:

```
age = int(raw_input("What is your age? ")).
```

Parse to int no matter what introduced.